# Balanced BSTs using hashmaps?

Tags: data-structures, hashmap, binary-search-tree

**BBSTs using a hash-map instead of pointers**

I was thinking about the idea to implement a balanced binary search tree using hash-maps. An implementation can be something like this : hash-map's **key** will be value inserted in the tree and hash-map's **value** will be a tuple of left value, right value and height (in case of AVL tree)

```
    10                     H[10] = {7, 15, 2}
   /  \                    H[7]  = {3, 8, 1}
  7    15          --->    H[15] = {nil, 18, 1}
 / \    \                  H[3] = H[8] = H[18] = {nil, nil, 0}
3   8    18
```

I don't think it provides any advantage over the standard implementation of trees other than the fact that you can search the value in constant time and then search for any successor or any other statistics which a BBST provides. We can already do this with the help of maintaining a hash-map pointing to nodes but in my opinion this implementation is easier.

Has anyone tried this? Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say whether it's a good or bad idea, although I can't see any particular benefit to it. It looks to me like inserting or removing nodes is going to be more complicated, especially if you want to keep the tree balanced.

You're also going to have some real trouble if your tree allows for duplicate keys.

I think you'd be better off with the traditional tree structure, and if you need O(1) lookup, add the hash map.

Comment: Inserting and removing nodes is not going to be an issue IMO. But duplicate keys is a really huge issue. 
I can't think of any advantage myself. Maybe less memory is needed but I am not sure.